# Thread : 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs in the NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, nspredicate

In my mac OS X application, I am getting this **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** signal in Core Data part (`NSPredicate`).

[image]

Code for reference:

```
[self.managedObjectContext reset];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[self.managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

//Setting Entity to be Queried
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FileTable"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_pk" ascending:NO]]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError* error;

NSString *uuid = uniqueId;

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid = %@", uuid];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

// Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
NSArray *fetchedRecords = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

// NSLog(@"fetchedRecords %@",fetchedRecords);

// Returning Fetched Records
return fetchedRecords;
```

I caught the stack trace for the above scenario

```
(
0   WEPA-PrintApp                       0x000000010a235969 WEPA-PrintApp + 47465
1   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9216acbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9205c1b4 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8c528ea1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f95725b -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 291
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f956fc6 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 191
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f953dc6 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 574
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8f953805 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8c548458 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8c5482c9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
10  AE                                  0x00007fff9047a99c _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 531
11  AE                                  0x00007fff9047a719 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 31
12  AE                                  0x00007fff9047a623 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295
13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff93e1b37e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f94fec6 _DPSNextEvent + 2665
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f94efd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f942f73 -[NSApplication run] + 594
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8f92e424 NSApplicationMain + 1832
18  WEPA-PrintApp                       0x000000010a250f96 WEPA-PrintApp + 159638
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff917ae5c9 start + 1
)
```

This crash occurs not all the time. And `uuid` here is `NSString`. Can any one provide the solution to accomplish the issue?

Comment: Where are you getting that `uniqueId` from?

Comment: uniqueId is a value assigned property that i declared in global. I am getting the uniqueId as NSString.  For my confirmation only, i am reassigning the value to NSString again.

Comment: Would you please share that piece of code also? And by the way, the trace seems to be completely unrelated  to the exception you are showing in the first screenshot.

Comment: @Raspu. Leave the screenshot as this occurs during my debug mode. I got the stack trace when i run as application.  I am sure that my app crashes with above stack trace. So how can i identify and solve my issue with the stack trace given above.

Comment: You should provide the code where do you create the unique identifier. This should be a problem on memory? Have you enabled zombies?

Comment: As @Raspu suggested the stack trace is not relevant here. Enable also all exceptions within Xcode and provide the right one.